# Accessing a file in the parent folder, for maven ZIP plugin

Tags: maven, parent, gitignore, maven-assembly-plugin

A project in my university requires the .git and .gitingnore to be outside the project folder. However it also requires that my .gitignore be included in the zip created by a maven package. I have put the .git, .gitignore and the project in the same parent folder. Basically what I am trying to achieve is something like this in the .xml file concerned with the maven zip plugin:

```
<fileSet>
        <directory>../</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>.gitignore</include>
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
```

in order to be able to access the .gitignore that is in the parent folder.
this however obviously does not work. Is there any way I could get a similar result?

Comment: Are you sure you did not misunderstand the requirements? Why should a `.gitignore` be part of the final zip?

Comment: thank you for the answer, but unfortunately not. They described that the .gitignore must be in the workspace and that it must be in the final zip. I wish i understood why...

Comment: So did you ask them about your problem before you posted it here?

Comment: Having the `.git` and `.gitignore` outside of the project directory does not make sense cause it's part of the project and in the root of the project...So it's not clear why and what the intention of those ideas/requirements are?

Comment: Thank you for everyone who answered, the logic behind what they want is unknown, it seems that they simply wanted make us do obscure research. My current code works I was simply missing the following tag before the includes tag:<useDefaultExcludes>false</useDefaultExcludes>.      And yes, we have a uni Forum, on which the reasoning behind this problem was questioned. The answer was that our understanding of the question was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the .gitignore file is excluded by maven from the zip. To include it, the following tag has to be put before the  tag:

```
<useDefaultExcludes>false</useDefaultExcludes>
```